# Why does my board get all scrambled like this?

Tags: c

The boards is getting printed correctly inside the first for but after it gets all scrambled up. The board is filled with numbers just cause im debugging.

```
int **allocMem(int nrows, int ncolumns){

  int **board = malloc( (nrows + 1) * sizeof(int *));
  for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
   board[i] = malloc( (ncolumns + 1) * sizeof(int));

  if (board == NULL) {
    printf("\t\nERROR::memory allocation\n\n" );
    free(board);
    return 0 ;
  }

  return board;
}
```

Here is the allocation first then this is the board

```
void makeBoard(int **board, int nrows, int ncolumns){
  int i = 0;
  printf("board being created \n");
  for(int lines = 0; lines < nrows + 1; lines++){
    for(int columns = 0; columns < ncolumns + 1; columns++){
      (*board + lines)[columns] = i++;
      printf("| %d ", (*board + lines)[columns] );
    }
    printf("| \n" );
  }
  printf("board after being created  \n");
  for(int lines = 0; lines < nrows + 1; lines++){
    for(int columns = 0; columns < ncolumns + 1; columns++) {
      printf("| %d ", (*board + lines)[columns] );
    }
    printf("| \n" );
  }
}
```

and this is the output

[image]

Comment: In `allocMem`: `for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)` should that be `for(int i = 0; i < nrows+1; i++)`?

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to `nrows` and `ncolumns` when you call `malloc()`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/KNjilJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(*board + lines)[columns]` should be `(*(board + lines))[columns]` because `*` has higher precedence than `+`.  Or you can simply write `board[lines][columns]`, which makes the 2-dimensional nature of the board clear.

In general, when `x` is a pointer, `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x+y)`.